# Speeding up simple loop program by multithreading or alternative

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, loops

I have a very simple program that converts .HEIC images to .JPEG images; this is a batch operation. This task is a simple loop that runs following code. The code takes quite long to process when processing a large batches of 1000+ images. (I am using nuget package FileOnQ.Imaging.Heif).

How can I speed up the process? Can I perform the loop execution on different threads? Or is there another alternative.

```
For each File as String in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(oBasePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      Dim oHEICimage As New HeifImage(FullPath)
      Dim oNewPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory, Name & ".jpeg")
      oHEICimage.PrimaryImage.Write(oNewPath)
Next
```

Note: I removed some code that determinates the file naming etc. because this is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes, you can do the image processing in multiple threads, but just running this exact code multiple times won't solve your problem, but you have to create some logic how you distribute your workload on different threads. Ie, each resource should only be handled once and you shouldn't create to many parallel threads, because that will slow down the overall process.

Comment: @derpirscher thank you for the fast feedback, highly appreciated. I am looking for some good samples but either there are not too many or my search input is no good. Do you have some pointers / samples suggestions?

Comment: The first step is to confirm that your processing is limited by something that can be sped up by parallelizing it.  It depends on how much of the processing is converting the file, and how much is loading the old file / writing the new one (and then, maybe even where the old and new are written).  If you're I/O bound on a single drive, running in parallel won't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a multithread example in a for loop, you can use Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

However, be aware of creating too many resources in the loop, as it may not speed up the processing. You can also limit the number of threads running running on the loop by specifying `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in [ParallelOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx).

For example:

```
Dim files As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(oBasePath, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(files, Sub(imgFile)
                                           Dim oHEICimage As New HeifImage(imgFile)
                                           Dim oNewPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(outDirectory, Name & ".jpeg")
                                           oHEICimage.PrimaryImage.Write(oNewPath)
                                        End Sub)
```